# decode the Value fetched in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to decode the value which I fetched. I fetched  and concat ',' to the value `$album.=$fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'].',';` I want to decode the value and send it to jsondata. Now 'albpic' return null.I got the json value as shown in image.

[image]

```
$alb = array();
$get_alb = mysql_query("select * from album");
while($fet_alb = mysql_fetch_array($get_alb)) {
     $id=$fet_alb['ID'];
     $alid=$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'];
     $albpic=mysql_query("select * from album_details where SUB_ID='$id'");
      $album='';        
       while($fet_pic=mysql_fetch_array($albpic))
       {
         $album.=$fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'].',';
       }
      // $album = substr($album,0,-1);
       $alb[] = array_merge(array('id' => $id),json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'], true),array('albpics'=>json_decode($album)));

 }  
echo json_encode($alb);

 $album={"media_type":"image/png","content_type":"alb_detail","website_id":"571710720","last_modified_date":"2015-11-23T05:27:03.806Z","thumnail_pic_loc":"link.png","large_pic_loc":"link.png","filter_type":"image/png","photodescription":"No Description","pic_id":"zhadb"},{"media_type":"image/png","content_type":"alb_detail","website_id":"571710720","last_modified_date":"2015-11-23T05:27:03.806Z","thumnail_pic_loc":"link.png","large_pic_loc":"link.png","filter_type":"image/png","photodescription":"No Description","pic_id":"zhadb"},{"media_type":"image/video","content_type":"alb_info","website_id":"571710720","last_modified_date":"2015-11-23T05:27:03.806Z","thumnail_pic_loc":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/fdgd/default.jpg","large_pic_loc":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/fdgd/hqdefault.jpg","filter_type":"image/video","videoname":"fdgd","photodescription":"dfgdfg","pic_id":"kg5k4"}
```

Comment: What output return by ` $album`  this variable. Please put in your question.

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

To use `json_decode()` the parameter you are passing should be in json_encoded format.

change this

```
$alb[] = array_merge(array('id' => $id),json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'], true),array('albpics'=>json_decode($album)));
```

to

```
$alb[] = array_merge(array('id' => $id),$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'], ,array('albpics'=>$album));
```

If `$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']` this is json encoded value, use

```
$arr = json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']);
$arr1 = imlpode(",",$arr);// this will give comma separated values.
```

Comment: As `$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']` contains json values. how could you use it in `array_merge()`

Answer (score 0):

Your `$album` variable does not return proper json values.

So, try to replace with below lines. Hope it will works for you.

```
 $alb[] = array_merge(array('id' => $id),json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'], true),array('albpics'=>json_decode("[".$album."]",true)));
```